# Sinon stub not working on exported function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I trying to stub a function which reloads a webpage.

```js
export function reloadPage() {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

This is how I am stubbing the function:

```js
import * as ref from 'file/where/reloadpage/is/defined';

describe('...', function () {
    ...
    before(function () {
       this.reloadStub = sinon.stub(ref, 'reloadPage');
    });
});
```

It is still not stubbing the method properly. My tests throw a "full page reload" error.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that the reload is happening there and that it's actually reaching that original, non-mocked function?

Comment: Yes! There is only one instance where I am reloading the page in my application, and I am pretty sure that the code is reaching the original non-mocked function

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

`index.ts`:

```js
export function reloadPage() {
  console.log('reload');
  window.location.reload();
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import * as ref from './';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('57519517', () => {
  let reloadStub;
  before(() => {
    reloadStub = sinon.stub(ref, 'reloadPage');
  });

  it('should mock reload page', () => {
    const logSpy = sinon.spy(console, 'log');
    ref.reloadPage();
    expect(reloadStub.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    expect(logSpy.notCalled).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 57519517
    ✓ should mock reload page


  1 passing (12ms)
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57519517